# С++ зачем указывать тип возвращаемого из функции так?

Tags: c++

```
auto F() -> string {
    return "23";
}
```

```
 -> string
```

Answer (score 4):

Это альтернативный вариант написания формата возвращаемого значения из функции. Он появился при введении в стандарт `C++11` лямда-функций. Формат описания лямда-функций начинается с `[]` и возвращаемое значение перед функцией написать невозможно.

```
auto f = []()-> string { return string("23"); }
```

Answer (score 4):

Это называется хвостовым возвращаемым значением. Основное преимущество в том, что оно находится уже в контексте и может использовать идентификаторы класса или аргументов.

```
struct t_Outer
{
    struct t_Inner{};

    auto foo(void) -> t_Inner *;
};

// Вместо 
// t_Outer::t_Inner * t_Outer::foo(void)
auto t_Outer::foo(void) -> t_Inner *
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

```
// вместо
// using t_Arg = int;
// t_Arg square(t_Arg num)
auto square(int num) -> decltype(num);
```